# Custom objects visible for all users

Tags: managed-package, permissions, permission-sets

I have a managed package with permission set for custom objects, VF pages, etc. When I install this package for a sysadmin user (granted access to only sys admin profile), I see that the custom objects are visible for other users as well. However the objects are not editable. I have not assigned the permission set to any user.

Is that the expected behavior? I would assume the objects would not be visible to any other users except Sysadmin.

Comment: In what sense are the objects visible? Is this a brand-new install of the package?

Comment: Yes this is a brand new install. For the user (for which I did not install the package), I can see that if I check: setup->Apps , the app shows up however it is not editable. Same goes for the custom objects, If I check Setup->Objects, I can see the custom objects and their fields, however they aren't editable as well. That said, I haven't installed the package for other profiles or assigned any permission set

Comment: It sounds like you're going into Setup and expecting some objects to be hidden in Setup/Create/Objects. All objects will always be displayed here, if the logged-in user has Setup access. The test would be to either check the Profile for the user you're concerned about, or login as that user and see if you can see the tabs, etc that are the problem.